# Как вызвать функцию в начале или каждый фрейм без использования Update & Start

Tags: c#, unity3d

Весь вопрос в заголовке. Как вызвать функцию в начале или каждый фрейм без использования Update & Start в Unity3d (если это важно).

Comment: В заголовке нет вопроса. Вообще здесь нет ни одного знака вопроса.

Comment: Update() выполняется каждый кадр. Как ты хочешь по другому то сделать?
Можешь использовать корутины, но если тебе нужно каждый кадр, то ты юзаешь Update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри порядок вызова событий

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Тебе подходит LateUpdate

> LateUpdate is called once per frame, after Update has finished.

Или "сопрограммы"(Coroutines)
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html

```
public IEnumerator Foo()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь вызвать метод в начале, используй Awake() или Main().

Если тебе не желательно использовать Update, то можно использовать корутины. Ты можешь создать корутин с бесконечным циклом(лучше с условием выхода), который вызовешь в Start().